# Object References,Threads and Garbage collection

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

One of the few things I know about Garbage collector is that it picks up the object which have no references.
Let `MyClass` is a class and I make an object of it by doing

```
MyClass object = new MyClass();
```

I can make it eligible for garbage collection even when my code is executing by doing

```
object = null;
```

But what happened to the objects which have no object references, like following statement.

```
new MyClass();
```

My doubt is really concerned to threads, I can create and execute a thread by following code.

```
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
     new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Does it work?");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("Nope, it doesnt...again.");
                } catch(InterruptedException v) {
                    System.out.println(v);
                }
            }  
        }.start();
 }
```

But the thread is having no reference to it, like you know I can create thread by having a object reference but May be I don't want to.

- Let the thread is doing a long long running Task, How the garbage collector will react to this?
- What will happen to the `new MyClass();` statement from the perspective of GC...

Answer (score 4):

GC looks at all live threads for stack traces so your `Thread` doesn't have a reference from the `main` thread, but it does from the currently executing one (the newly created thread).

GC looks for the reachable objects from so called GC roots, one of the roots are all threads.

Answer (score 2):

> ...object which have no references...

Let's just be clear about what that means.  Discussions about GC often distinguish objects that are *traceable* from a *GC root* from objects that are *not traceable*.

"Traceable" means, that you follow a chain of object references starting from a gc root, and eventually reach the object in question.  The gc roots basically are all of the `static` variables in the program, and all of the parameters and all of the local variables of every active method call in every thread.

"Active method call" means that a call has happened for which the corresponding `return` has not yet happened.

So, if some active method in some thread has a reference to a `Foo` instance, and the `Foo` instance has a reference to a `Bar` instance, and the `Bar` instance has a reference to a `Baz` instance; then the `Baz` instance is "traceable", and it won't be collected.

In every thread, there are method activations below the `run()` call on the thread's stack, and at least one of those method activations has a reference to the `Thread` instance that manages the thread.  So a `Thread` object will never be GCd while the thread that it manages still is running.

Also, somewhere in the dark heart of the JVM, there's a static list of all of the `Class` instances, so none of them will ever be GCd either.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM keeps a reference to all the running thread so if a thread is running it will not be garbage collected. Also if your object is referenced by a running thread it would not be garbage collected.